# Sequelize Insert transaction (two tables, multiple rows)

Tags: transactions, sequelize.js, multiple-insert

Two tables: post and post_resources.
The logic I want to implement:
Whenever I add data to post table, I want to add resources as well to the post_resources table, with the same foreign key of PostId

How I'm doing it:

```
const post = {
    name: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
}

try {
  const result = await sq.transaction(async (t) => {
     await Post.create(post, { transaction: t })
          .then(async data => {
               await PostResources.create({
                   PostId: data.id,
                   name: req.body.title,
                   url: req.body.url,
                }, { transaction: t })
           })
     });

     res.status(200).json(result)

} catch (error) {
       console.log(error || 'Error occured in transaction');
}
```

Ps: the url is an array of urls to insert into post_ressources along with the same PostId !important

Please feel free to ask for any further details, thank you

Comment: And what's the issue here?

Comment: this error occurs before completing that transaction on the second table..
const error = new Error(`${options.transaction.finished} has been called on this transaction(${options.transaction.id}), you can no longer use it. (The rejected query is attached as the 'sql' property of this error)`);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `await` and `then` in the same time, which is a mistake because they are similar.

Your error says that you already commited the transaction so a solution would be like this:

```
const post = {
    name: req.body.title,
    description: req.body.description,
}
const t = await sequelize.transaction();
try {
     const resultPost = await Post.create(post, { transaction: t })
     const resultPostResources = await PostResources.create({
        PostId: resultPost.id,
        name: req.body.title,
        url: req.body.url,
        }, {transaction: t})
     await t.commit();
     res.status(200).json(result)
}catch (error) {
     console.log(error || 'Error occured in transaction');
}
```

Now you commit the transaction only after both Creation queries and also you get the values from the first one to use in second one.
Note that `create` returns the created object, so you can make use of it

Comment: Played around with it, and it worked..
Understanding the errors I was making helped..
Thank you for enlightening the way.